# IBM Cloud CLI Softlayer plugin: How to pass filters?

Tags: command-line-interface, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the [Softlayer commands in the IBM Cloud CLI](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cloud-cli-ibmcloud_cli#classic-service-commands) to manager classic infrastructure. Following the [documentation about the Softlayer API](https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Location_Datacenter/) I want to filter for specific data centers and their regions.

In general, the commands allow to pass in the following parameters:

```
OPTIONS:
   --init value        Init parameter (default: 0)
   --mask value        Object mask: use to limit fields returned
   --parameters value  Append parameters to web call
   --limit value       Result limit (default: 0)
   --offset value      Result offset (default: 0)
```

So I am trying to use `--parameters` to a[pply a filter like shown here](https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/object-filters/).

The following is returning all objects and not filtering. Other variations do not work either:

```
ibmcloud sl call-api SoftLayer_Location_Group getAllObjects --parameters 'object_filter={"locationGroupTypeId":1}'
```

How do I apply filters to the API call using the IBM Cloud CLI command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the ibmcloud cli does not support object filters.

I suggest you to try using slcli:

Use the following slcli command to see the object filter option:

```
slcli call-api --help
```

Output:

```
Usage: slcli call-api [OPTIONS] SERVICE METHOD [PARAMETERS]...

  Call arbitrary API endpoints with the given SERVICE and METHOD.

  Example::

      slcli call-api Account getObject     slcli call-api Account getVirtualGuests --limit=10 --mask=id,hostname
      slcli call-api Virtual_Guest getObject --id=12345     slcli call-api Metric_Tracking_Object getBandwidthData
      --id=1234 \         "2015-01-01 00:00:00" "2015-01-1 12:00:00" public     slcli call-api Account
      getVirtualGuests \         -f 'virtualGuests.datacenter.name=dal05' \         -f 'virtualGuests.maxCpu=4' \
      --mask=id,hostname,datacenter.name,maxCpu     slcli call-api Account getVirtualGuests \         -f
      'virtualGuests.datacenter.name IN dal05,sng01'

Options:
  --id TEXT                       Init parameter
  -f, --filter TEXT               Object filters. This should be of the form: 'property=value' or
                                  'nested.property=value'. Complex filters like betweenDate are not currently
                                  supported. (multiple occurrence permitted)
  --mask TEXT                     String-based object mask
  --limit INTEGER                 Result limit
  --offset INTEGER                Result offset
  --output-python / --no-output-python
                                  Show python example code instead of executing the call
  -h, --help                      Show this message and exit.
```

Reference:

https://softlayer-api-python-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cli/

Comment: I am logged in with `ibmcloud` and want to and have to use that CLI command. `slcli` is not installed.